# Jsoup parse error (tag table within tag p)

Tags: html, jsoup

When I parse this code with Jsoup:

```
<p>
<table>[...]</table>
</p>
```

Jsoup returns:

```
<p></p>
<table>[...]</table>
```

Is this a mistake? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with your example not being "valid" html.  I believe a table cannot exist within a p tag.  Jsoup is probably enforcing correct HTML.

Comment: if i replace the p tag with default tag and then parse code with jsoup ....works well.

Answer (score 0):

jsoup is very intelligent. It will reform your input text to the valid html conent, if you use its default parsing method.

`Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);`

Actually, jsoup can handle xml-like text (certainly, including html and xml). You can try follwing method to parse xml-like text. It will not reform your input, and parse the input as it is.

`Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());`

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question of if the return from Jsoup is a mistake or not.

Comment: @verdammelt,yes, it may return invalid html code from Jsoup.But the questioner may want to find a way of how to avoid the checking and reforming process of intelligent jsoup.