# Using Jsoup (the Java html parser) with Handlebarsjs

Tags: coldfusion, jsoup, handlebars.js

So, I'm using jsoup and when I display the content returned I Get:

```
{{#ifcond="" pagetitle="" this.name}}
```

I'm doing this like `local.htmlObj.Body().Html()`

When I need it to be return like:

```
{{#ifCond PAGETITLE this.NAME}}
```

Here what I'm doing

```
<cfset paths    = [] />
<cfset paths[1] = expandPath("/javaloader/lib/jsoup-1.7.1.jar") />
<cfset loader   = createObject("component", "javaloader.JavaLoader").init( paths ) />
<cfset obj      = loader.create( "org.jsoup.Jsoup" ) />

<cfset local.htmlObj = local.jsoupObj.parse( local.template ) />

<cfloop array="#local.htmlObj.select('.sidebar_left')#" index="element">
        <cfif element.attr('section') EQ "test">
            <cfset element.append('HTML HERE') />
        </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

`local.template` is my template that is made up of a ton of different handlebar files That im pulling for different places. I'm constructing one handlebar file that gets returned.

Comment: how to make it jsoup return the handlebar script like "{{#ifCond PAGETITLE this.NAME}}". I'm passing it in that way but I get "{{#ifcond="" pagetitle="" this.name}}" in return

Comment: JSoup expects HTML. Your Handlebars code isn't HTML (it's a template language that outputs HTML). You can possibly do what you're trying to achieve purely with Handlebars itself. If not, use JSoup on the HTML _after_ Handlebars has output it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that JSoup is trying to parse invalid HTML before it lets you access it.  A slight easier to understand example of this behavior can be seen if you fetch the following HTML (seen in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994261/jsoup-parse-error-tag-table-within-tag-p)):

```
<p>
<table>[...]</table>
</p>
```

It will return:

```
<p></p>
<table>[...]</table>
```

In your case the Handelbars code is seen as attributes which in valid html always have a value (think `checked="checked"`). As far as I can tell there is no way to disable this behavior.  It's really the wrong tool for the job you are trying to do.  A cleaner approach would be to just fetch the document as a stream and save it to a string.

Comment: I appreciate you taking time to help me on this. Thanks again